# Print value of __m128 datatype in gdb debugger

Tags: c++, gdb, sse, simd, intrinsics

Is there any way to print the value of a variable of datatype `__m128` (used for Intel SSE intrinsics) directly in GDB? The command `print $myVariable` works fine for `int` and `float` but not for `__m128`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a pain, but I usually do it like this:

`gdb> p *(float *)&v@4`

This is assuming that `v` is `__m128`. You can apply the same principle for e.g. an `__m128i` vector of `unsigned char`:

`gdb> p /x *(unsigned char *)&v@16`

Comment: Thanks for this! I added a custom command called p__m128i to my ~/.gdbinit file so now this is always available.

Comment: If you're single-stepping asm (compiler-generated or otherwise), `display $xmm0.v4_float` works well to watch what's in XMM0 after every step.